# How to calculate Average from a percentile value

Tags: statistics

I have a dataset which contains percentile values of all households spending more than 200 $ on food in a ZIP Code.

Sample Dataset:

```
+-----------+------------+
|   Zip4    | PERCENTILE |
+-----------+------------+
| 773797186 | 38         |
| 341133251 | 98         |
|  64892055 | null       |
| 750873252 | null       |
| 774795260 | 52         |
| 947062409 | 48         |
| 600913354 | 56         |
| 330406106 | 61         |
| 282111497 | 64         |
| 344829306 | 64         |
| 330635038 | 86         |
| 770576650 | 61         |
| 221502421 | 12         |
| 786602374 | 11         |
+-----------+------------+
```

I also have the total number of homes in a ZIP. Is there any way I can calculate the average spend by every home on food present in a particular ZIP?

Comment: Is there a particular software you are using?

Comment: I can use any software to implement this.